# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "¡Uh que la canción!"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Mi abuela, que en paz descanse, siempre me decía varias expresiones curiosas de su pueblo (fue del sur de Chihuahua, México).  Entre ellas, hay una que siempre me confundía:

> ¡Uh que la canción!

Se me hace que la usaba para decir algo como "¡Qué barbaridad!", es decir, para expresar un disgusto con la situación con que se encuentre.  Pero nunca he encontrado el origen de esta expresión. ¿Hay alguien que me puede explicar por qué se dice así en este contexto?

Answer (score 6):

Es un eufemismo para evitar decir una grosería.

> *A que la chin... canción.*

Es una expresión de hastío por una situación que no se debería repetir pero vuelve a pasar. Como una canción.

Answer (score 3):

Mi tía también la decía mucho.  Solo que ella la utilizaba cuando volvía a ocurrir algo que le molestaba. Cómo las canciones suelen repetir un verso le ocurría lo que le molestaba otra vez. Es como esa de "otra vez la burra al trigo".

Comment: Hola Alvaro y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Así como está, esto es más un comentario que una respuesta. Date una vuelta por [answer] y el [tour] para ver qué tipo de respuestas son valoradas aquí. Básicamente, nos gusta que contesten a la pregunta, tengan explicaciones y, a poder ser, algún ejemplo. Dale a [edit] para mejorarla. Si no, deberemos moverla a la zona de comentarios.